# I am working on android camera app,I want to capture image and change its background using green screen chroma key effect

Tags: android

I am working on android camera app,I want green screen chroma key effect to captured image.
I have used http://code.google.com/p/chroma-key-project/downloads/list this chroma key project with my code,but it doesn't make that much sense to me.I am capturing image in green/blue background with chroma key effect then I need to set white background to it.. please help me out.
I am using this code for tablet but the program is automatically crashed and It gives this type of error "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget"..why? and what should i do for this?

Comment: Now it gives null pointer exception to this line from preview.java page. camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder); // <9> why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is rater simple, your application does not have enough memory to handle the bitmap size. What you should do is use smaller bitmaps to work with.

Rolf

Edit: it could be useful if you post some code y'r using.

Comment: thanks for suggesting.That error is resolved now..but giving null pointer exception to this line from preview.java page. camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);  // <9>  why?

Comment: It's simple i think, your camera object is null because the device does not have a camera... from the developers site:

Camera.open()
Since: API Level 1
Creates a new Camera object to access the first back-facing camera on the device. If the device does not have a back-facing camera, this returns null.

Comment: But you should make a new question on this problem, because it's totally different. And do some more research your self. Cause the only way to learn is, by searching for you own answers. At least that's what i think.