# Android video remove chroma key background

Tags: android, android-ndk, video-processing, chromakey

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813089/i-am-working-on-android-camera-app-i-want-to-capture-image-and-change-its-backgr) question.

It is very similar: 
I want to record a video with android camera.
After that with a library remove the background, which is with chroma key. 
First I think I should use android NDK in order to escape from SDK memory limitation and use the whole memory. 
The length of the video is short, a few seconds so maybe is able to handle it. 
I would prefer to use an SDK implementation and set the `android:largeHeap="true"` , because of mismatching the .so files architecture.

Any library suggestion for SDK or NDK please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO you should prefer NDK based solution, since video processing is a CPU-consuming operation and java code won't give you a better performance. Moreover, the most popular and reliable media-processing libraries are often written in C or C++.

I'd recommend you to take a look at [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/). It offers reach abilities to cope with multimedia. [`chromakey`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-chromakey) filter may help you to remove green background (or whatever color you want). Then you can use another video as new background, if needed. See [`blend`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blend_002c-tblend) filter docs.

[Filters](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Description) are a nice and powerful concept. They may be used both via `ffmpeg` tool command line or via [`libavfilter`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/group__lavfi.html) API. For the former case you should find `ffmpeg` binary compiled for android and run it with traditional `Runtime.exec()`. For the latter case - you need to write native code, that creates proper filter graph and performs processing. This code must be linked against FFmpeg libraries.

Comment: I want to try this. I am new to android. So its a bit confusing what you wrote. Can you please specify exact steps with which I can proceed speedily? I would be really grateful to you.

Comment: FFmpeg library support for this. i also got solutions by 

String[] ffmpegComplexCommand = {"-y","-i",backgroundimage.jpg,"-i",SorcevideoPath, "-filter_complex", "[1:v]chromakey=0x3BBD1E:0.03:0.2[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[o]", "-codec:v",
               "libx264",
               "-codec:a",
               "copy",
               "-crf",
               "30",
               "-preset",
               "ultrafast","-map", "[o]", "-map", "1:a", output.getAbsolutePath()};