# How to add animation before the opening of a new activity?

Tags: android, android-animation

I would like to add an animation before the opening of a new Android Empty Activity. Something like a chroma-keyed video played on top of the current activity and at the end of it, the secondary activity opens up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a splash activity that includes your animation, and you implement an [AnimationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener). Inside the method `onAnimationEnd()` you create the intent that takes you to the second activity. Don't forget to set the splash activity as the Launcher activity on your manifest.

```
animationObject.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        Intent intent = new Intent (SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

**EDIT:** if you want to play a video with media player instead you use a [playback listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener) and run the same intent from `onCompletion()`

Comment: thanks for the answer...is it possible to chroma-key a video? like green screen

Comment: do you have a video that's already filmed on green screen and want to edit the background? not sure I understand what you have and what you want to achieve?!

Comment: is that functionality part of your app? if so check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40278174/10300673 If not you just use another app from the play store to create your video and then embed the final product in your activity

Answer (score 0):

After your startActivity method use the overridePendingTranistion and put the animations in it

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
            }
        });
```

The xml animations are as follows
enter.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

exit.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```